# testing recursive function without parameter

Tags: java

I've got this validator method that checks whether user's input is correct.

It's working as intended but I can't find a solution to test passPhoneNumber() method

I was thinking about adding a parameter to passPhoneNumber() method but it would break the code.

```
public static boolean phoneNumberValidator(String phoneNumber) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PHONE_NUMBER_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);

    if(!matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.print("Invalid phone number. ");
        return false;

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public static String passPhoneNumber() {
    System.out.print("Enter phone number (format 111222333): ");
    String phoneNumber = scanner.nextLine();

    if(phoneNumberValidator(phoneNumber)) {
        return phoneNumber;

    } else {
        return passPhoneNumber();
    }
}
```

My pattern is:

```
private static final String PHONE_NUMBER_PATTERN = "^\\d{9}$";
```

Just 9 digits, nothing else.

Comment: So you'll write some test methods, in some other class, that just call `phoneNumberValidator` directly, with different inputs, and verify that the result is as expected.  I would recommend using JUnit or TestNG for this.

Comment: so in other words I should test only phoneNumberValidator ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking how to test `phoneNumberValidator`.  I didn't read carefully enough.  If you want to test `passPhoneNumber` as well, I would recommend mocking `scanner`.  In other words, have your own scanner object, with predetermined input, and use it instead of `System.in`.

Comment: Also, why would you use recursion for this?  Why not just a loop?

Comment: cannot come up with how would that loop look like

Comment: If I were writing this, I would have all the logic in one method, not two.  That method would have a "forever loop" (`for(;;)` or `while(true)`) with a `return` statement in the event of the validation passing.  You could pass a `Scanner` into that method, from elsewhere, that you could use for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your method by using a do-while loop:

```
public static String passPhoneNumber() {
    String phoneNumber = "";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter phone number (format 111222333): ");
        phoneNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    } while(!phoneNumberValidator(phoneNumber));
    scanner.close();
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

Then you can use a testing framework like JUnit to decouple your code from the test.
In JUnit you have a test class like this:

```
public class PhoneNumberValidatorTest extends TestCase {

    public void testValidator() {
        assertTrue("Valid number 1", PhoneClass.phoneNumberValidator("123456789"));
        assertTrue("Valid number 2", PhoneClass.phoneNumberValidator("000000000"));
        assertFalse("Invalid input 1", PhoneClass.phoneNumberValidator("0"));
        assertFalse("Invalid input 2", PhoneClass.phoneNumberValidator("abcdefghi"));
    }

    public void testPasser() {
        // Test with a valid input
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("123456789".getBytes()));
        assertEquals("123456789", PhoneClass.passPhoneNumber());

        // Test with another valid input
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("000000000".getBytes()));
        assertEquals("000000000", PhoneClass.passPhoneNumber());

        // Test with 1 invalid inputs and then 1 valid input
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("0\n111222333".getBytes()));
        assertEquals("111222333", PhoneClass.passPhoneNumber());

        // Test with 2 invalid inputs and then 1 valid input
        System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("abcdefghi\n12346578\n122333444".getBytes()));
        assertEquals("122333444", PhoneClass.passPhoneNumber());

        // Reset to the original System.in
        System.setIn(System.in);
    }
}
```

The `testPasser()` method uses an override of the `System.in` to our predetermined inputs.
Since the `passPhoneNumber()` will loop till it receives a valid phone number input, we always need to only test for the final valid number in the `assertEquals`.

I hope this is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: I should have precised my question. I already did some testing for the validator. I'm having trouble with testing the other method - passPhoneNumber(). If i refactor passPhoneNumber() like you did I still have parameterless function that is quite hard to test. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: yes! that is the answer I was looking for. Thank you VERY MUCH